# .net Missing Method Exception .CTOR

Tags: c#

The projects in my VS 2019 solution reference a code library. I added the following class constructor within the library:

```
public class appLogic
{
    private DB db = new DB();

    public appLogic(DB dbx = null)
    {
        if (dbx != null)
        {
            db = dbx;
        }
    }
```

When a method within the appLogic class is called from a project using a "using" statement in the top of the controller everything works fine. However, if the method is called like so,

```
Lib.viewModels.app.appLogic alogic = new Lib.viewModels.app.appLogic();
x = alogic.method();
```

I end up with the following error:
**Method not found: 'Void Lib.Models.appLogic..ctor()'**.

Why does using a "using" statement differ? And if I cannot use a "using" statement, is there some way to instantiate the class so I don't receive the error?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] for the working version and the error version?

Comment: my guess is that it doesn't support default values this way, just pass "null" explicitly to the constructor

Comment: I suspect somehow you're compiling against an old version of the library, but then executing against the new one. Basically adding that constructor is a breaking change. If you clean everything, then recompile everything against the new version of the library, it should be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a constructor with parameters is a breaking change that removes the default `.ctor`. If you want to maintain backward compatibility in the library just add a second constructor overload and don't use default parameters in public api:

```
public appLogic() : this(null)
{
}

public appLogic(DB dbx)
{
    if (dbx != null)
    {
        db = dbx;
    }
}
```

Default parameters might become a problem when you consume a library from another programming language or use old version of library during compilation.

Read more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1026?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm!